# Computer calculation: is there a better word than "オンザフライ" to say "on-the-fly"?

Tags: word-choice, translation

As a valuable feature of my software product, I want to say that results are calculated on-the-fly, meaning the user does not have to wait and receive results by email: results are displayed after two seconds.

Should I say オンザフライ as advised by my friend [alc](http://eow.alc.co.jp/On-the-fly)?

The context would be something like "オンザフライ結果表示" in a bullet list

Comment: オンザフライ is indeed not unheard of in documentations of computer software and hardware, but it drives me nuts (part of me screams, “That’s not Japanese!!”).  Thank you for trying to translate it better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could say

- **その場で**結果を表示

For example, an article introducing Google's Instant Previews was titled "[Google、検索結果をその場でプレビューできる「Instant Previews」発表](http://www.itmedia.co.jp/news/articles/1011/10/news024.html)".

I think this is the most natural way to put it. The downside is you lose the conciseness coming from the use of all-kanji/katakana compound nouns.

Comment: I like this one for two reasons: 1) it's accurate, and 2) it's Real Japanese (not some kanji conglomeration imported from China).

Answer (score 2):

Doubt there is anything better than katakana for the exact term "on the fly", but if you mean to say "real-time"/"immediate", perhaps 即時に【そくじに】 would do?

Comment: Yes, 即時に seems to have the meaning I am looking for, thank you! Real-time might be a bit too strong, since my calculation still takes 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to state that the calculations are done as needed in response to demand, [随時](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E9%9A%8F%E6%99%82/UTF-8/) (ずいじ) would be a possible option. (随時更新される結果表示, maybe?) The ALC page I linked gives "running", "continuous", "as-needed", and similar terms as candidate translations for 随時. But if the quickness of your calculations is the main focus, I think Dave's 即時 would be better.

Comment: I should have added that the calculation is only performed once. It is a kind of the final step in the workflow of the website.